# Finding shortest equal travel distance on 2 circles to result in defined relative distance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Struggling to align 2 handles with given center points to match defined tie distance while traveling an equal distance on each of the circle circumference.

As you can see on the image, we have defined circle centers, handles radius and starting points. We know that each of the points, p1 and p2, will have to travel equal distance along each own circles circumference until they both reach position where distance is equal to given tie (D).

So far I have tried many things, starting from the least relevant, but figured that:

```
s1 = s2 = theta1(rad) * r1 = theta2(rad) * r2
```

therefore

```
K = r1/r2
theta2(rad) = theta1(rad) * K
```

Distance ^2 is equal to

```
(
      (c1[0] + cos(startAngle1+theta1) * r1)
    - (c2[0] + cos(startAngle2+K * theta1) * r2)
) ^ 2
+
(
      (c1[1] + sin(startAngle1+theta1) * r1)
    - (c2[1] + sin(startAngle2+K * theta1) * r2)
) ^ 2
```

Where starting angles are calculated absolutely to the coordinate system.
Above formula works fine on my simulation, but I am unable to solve it for distance = 'given value'. Regardless of how I twist it around(so far). I've considered aligning circles first and making both points move in a positive(clockwise) direction, as you see on the image. Any ideas or hints are appreciated!

#UPDATE regarding @Moti tangents suggestion (in the comments):
[image]

Comment: You are missing a measure - total arcs + tie or another input. I would say that actually you are looking for $\theta$s

Comment: Also note that D is the part of the tangent to the circles between them.

Comment: Start with calculating D.

Comment: @Moti The diagram is hard to read, but from the description of the problem I don't think the segment of length $D$ necessarily lies on a tangent to either circle.

Comment: If not, the line at points P1 and P2 will be broken

Comment: @Moti, thanks for your input. Knowing any one of the thetas would definitely solve the quest, as getting p1n and p2n is a short stretch from there. How might total arcs + tie work? What are different measures to consider? Sadly, D(tie) is not a part of the tangents between circles, since starting points may so be chosen that target position will show it clear (will update the question with simulation print screen shortly)

Comment: If I understand correctly your "physical" challenge - You have a string attached to two points, each on another pully, and you try to rotate each pully in such way that the string along the pully will have the same length. In such cases D MUST be tangent to both pullies.

Comment: @Moti, please see an update in the question body. You've got the physical background to it precisely

Comment: Your picture is totally confusing. How it is related to your original picture - radiuses, points, tie... If I understand the problem, when the string is properly stretched it is going from one pully to the other tangent.

Comment: @Moti I suppose I am missing something. Help me understand (see an image replaced with an alternate to preserves format of original one of the question)

Comment: I assume that a string goes from P1 to P2. How the Pin are defined? If I understand correctly your problem, D will be on the other side of the circles - again tangent.

Comment: @Moti, as you can see from the second AND first images, nether p1-p2 nor p1n-p2n is a tangent. According to problem description we are given two circles, with defined centers, radiuses, and handle start positions(such that guarantee an intersection at a distance of tie if turned clockwise at the same speed: travel distance/time). We are looking to find out what distance both handles will have to travel before they are at exactly the D(tie) distance to each other. Not sure what is the exact ground of your denial or if this is a deliberate trolling, but I have room for nether, thank you much.

Comment: The trouble is that you were not specifying the problem right if I now understand it. The D is a distance maintained rigidly between the points P1n and P 2n - right? Than I do not think that S1 can = S2. S2 is a function of S1. Your assertion that S1=S2 was misleading!

Comment: .......... s1=s2.